# Accessing files using folder name and ~folder name

Tags: windows, directory

When I try to access a folder:

```
cd "c:\users\myname\google drive\apache-tomcat-7.0.25"
```

it works fine. However when I try:

```
cd C:\Users\myname\GOOGLE~1\apache-tomcat-7.0.25
```

it doesn't (folder not found). It seems that when I go to C:\Users\myname\GOOGLE~1\ and try to look for apache-tomcat-7.0.25, i'ts not there. Is there some way I could make windows re-index that folder or something so that it knows apache-tomcat-7.0.25 is under C:\Users\myname\GOOGLE~1 too?

Comment: Is 8.3 filename creation enabled on your system? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007

Comment: Is there another "Google something" and the one you want is actually Google~2 or Google~3, etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following steps

1. I had another folder called Google Drive 2 within C:\Users\myname\ . I deleted that (didnt need it).
2. I used dir /x /a to get short names for all folders (even hidden)
3. I found that the short name was Google~2, and used it in my CATALINA_HOME. It works now.